# Accessing Database with windows service

Tags: sql-server-2005, ms-access, c#-2.0, service

I was implemented a windows application which is working perfectly.

The concept is to read an Access Database and export to MS SQL Server 2005 Database.

Now i want to make it as windows service and half way done. The problem is it is not working (Not updating the database).

The service was installed perfectly and running but not updating the database. I made that service as "Local Service", "Network Service", "Local System" and "User" bu not working for any of this type.

Can any one help me out for solving this.

The development environment is MS Visual Studio 2005, C#.NET, MS Access, MSSQL SERVER 2005 and Network supported Environment.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you realize [the functionality has been built into SQL Server, called Linked Servers](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/Microsoft-Access/Configuring-a-Linked-Microsoft-Access-Server-on-SQL-2005-Server/), since SQL Server 2000?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with Linked Server or an SSIS job running on SQL Agent which may well have been easier but... to tackle your question itself:

You mention trying different accounts to run the service - have you granted any of those accounts the appropriate rights on your target database to allow the service to update the data.  Do they also have rights on your source (Access) database to read it.

Have you checked the Event Logs on the server and the SQL Server logs to look for reported errors, failed logins etc?

You could hook up the debugger to your running service to try and identify the problem whilst it's running or alternatively you need to write in some kind logging statements so that you can identify where your code is getting up to before it fails and log out the error message(s) so give you something to work with.